# Logrotate not rotating my logs

Tags: ubuntu, cron, logrotate

Running on Ubuntu 14.04, I have the following logrotate config under `/etc/logrotate.d/logstash`

```
/opt/app/logs/logstash*.log {
        size 1g
        create 700 app app
        rotate 5
}
```

This log gets big pretty fast, so I wanted the logrotate cronjob to run on an hourly basis as well as on a daily basis. I copied `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` to `/etc/cron.hourly/logrotate` and executed `/etc/init.d/cron reload`

After about 18 hours, log was never rotated and is not showing up on `/var/lib/logrotate/status`

Any ideas/

Comment: you have a 1g size  in the params of the cronjob ....are you sure its getting that big  *HOURLY* ?  I ask since a failure  to meet  size => 1g  would presumably  fail to run the rotation

Comment: Yes, it gets to that size on an hourly basis. In any case, if it doesn't get to 1GB after 1 hour, but after two hours, it will simply rotate it WHEN it's 1GB (while checking on an hourly basis), correct?

Comment: Do you have confirmation in the logs that logrotate runs at all?  Or does it still run daily and rotate the log?

Comment: @paul I was using `1g` instead of `1G`. Everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: missed that ---case sensitive those  crons are lol

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I was using `1g` instead of `1G`.